# PowerShell Regex to find " Version 12.3 "

Tags: regex, powershell, boolean

In a string such as:

`CustomerDisplayVersionNumber : Version 12.3 (build 567.89)`

How can I, using a regex, return true if the version number is exactly `12.3`

There is the slight, but real possibility that the version number might contain a service pack version. For example

`CustomerDisplayVersionNumber : Version 12.3.4 (build 567.89)`

Which leads me to believe it will be safer to check for `[space]Version 12.3.nnnn[space]`.

Comment: Regex `[space]Version 12.3.nnnn[space]` will not match your first example `Version 12.3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex `"\sVersion (\d+\.\d+(\.\d+)?)\s"` will satisfy all provided examples

```
 @('CustomerDisplayVersionNumber : Version 12.3 (build 567.89)', 'CustomerDisplayVersionNumber : Version 12.3.4 (build 567.89)', 'CustomerDisplayVersionNumber : Version 12.3.9999 (build 567.89)') | % { [regex]::Match($_, "\sVersion (\d+\.\d+(\.\d+)?)\s").Success }
```

Answer (score 1):

use this regex `\s+Version \d+\.\d+\.\d+\s+`